# How remove emoji Magnifying glass in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, emoji

What I tried:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');
```

in css:

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger img {
display: none !important; ---///this works in chrome but not in mozilla
```

}
in js i tried without and with setTimeout:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
    $('woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger').find('img').removeAttr('alt');
    $('woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger').empty() ---////this tried when remove supports emoji in WP(see first 2 remove_action())
    $('woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger').contents().remove()---////this tried when remove supports emoji in WP(see first 2 remove_action())
  },2000)
```

Also i went to woocommerce plugin assets/js/single-product.js and remove this glass from `this.$target.prepend( '<a href="#" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger">HERE IT WAS</a>')`

But still I have this:[image: magWoo]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove Magnifying glass icon and disable zoom function on product page Woocommerce, you can follow this full tutorial [Remove Magnifying glass icon and disable zoom function on product page Woocommerce](https://wooexplorer.com/remove-magnifying-glass-icon-and-disable-zoom-function-woocommerce/):

**Edit woocommerce.css**

Connect to your website using FTP protocol, then go to /youwebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css

Edit this file with text editor tool and find class: `.woocommerce div.product div.images .woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger`, add display:none; to this class and it will be like this:

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images .woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: .5em;
    right: .5em;
    font-size: 2em;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background: #fff;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

You can also hide Magnifying glass icon using your child theme'css file

```
.single-product .woocommerce-product-gallery .woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This what i did, not ideal, but...

```
setTimeout(() => {$('.woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger').find('img').detach();
$('.woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger').text(' ');
},1000)
```

`setTimeout()` is needed, maybe better  put this into `after_setup_theme` hook, without setTimeout, but this works for me.